# IXMLDOMNode type doesn't fit as parameter in VBA in Win 7

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

Why this code not always works on Windows 7 64bit
(Office Word 2016 32bit), MSXML6 in references.

Works on Win10:

```
Function GetNodeText(ByVal node As IXMLDOMNode) As String
    If IsNothing(node) Then
        Exit Function
    End If
   GetNodeText = node.text
End Function

Function IsNothing(x) As Boolean
   IsNothing = False
   If IsObject(x) Then
     If TypeName(x) = "Nothing" Then
       IsNothing = True
     End If
   End If
 End Function
```

But doesn't work in Win7 (Error: Type Mismatch) during call `GetNodeText` function.

I have to change parameter type to Variant then works:

```
Function GetNodeText(ByVal nodeVar As Variant) As String
   Dim node as IXMLDOMNode
   Set node = nodeVar 
   If IsNothing(node) Then
      Exit Function
   End If
   GetNodeText = node.text
End Function
```

But I dont'like that solution

Comment: Is it possible that different Versions of the MSXML6  Library are installed? Although this shouldn't matter....

Also, why are you using your own IsNothing Function? you can do this: `If someObject Is Nothing Then Exit Function/Sub`

Comment: IsNothing found somewhere and works for me. I'll check versions.

Comment: Thera are differences in msxml6.dll between systems:

**Win10**
     `File version: 6.30.16299.726 (date: 2018.09.25 06:15)`

**Win7**
    `File version: 6.30.7601.24260 (date: 2018.09.09 02:43)`
That could be a reason?

Comment: What does the calling code like? The error you're getting relates to the calling expression, not your `GetNodeText` function. You're attempting to pass it something that can't be coerced into an `IXMLDOMNode`.

Comment: **1)** Drop the `IsNothing()` function, it's useless ("it works" and "it is useful" are different things). `If node Is Nothing` is 100% enough. **2)** Don't use `ByVal` here, objects are meant to be passed by reference. **3)** Windows 7 and Windows 10 should not make any difference. (I've tested it, it doesn't).

Comment: Not using IsNothing and passing ByRef doestn't change anything! Still the same error. I pass to GetNodeText function node as IXMLDOMNode. I'll prepare example.

Comment: Ops... When I prepare example - works on it, but in my code (I cant't show it) doesn't work. But now I have other issue - "Object library feature not supported" when try to pass DomDocument as parameter....

Comment: @Tomalak I know that for you sounds unbelievable but for me it doesnt work, when function is in other template and this template is in references.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. If you can't show a working reproduction of the error then I can't really help you. You don't have to show your application code, you only need to create something that has the same error behavior. If fact I would even prefer if you don't show your application code, but write an example *from scratch* that produces your error instead.

Comment: `IsNothing = False` in the beginning of `IsNothing` function is redundant because by default Boolean function returns `False`.